# initialize mixed structure in C

Tags: c

I have a structure in C say

```
typedef struct __X {
    char AA[10];
    int A;
    char BB[10];
    int B;
    ..
    ..
    ..
    char ZZ[10];
    int Z;
} _X;
```

How can I initialize a structure with bare minimal code, provided that `int` should be initialized with 0 and `char` with ' ' space.

One solution I know is:

```
memset(_X,0,sizeof(_X));
```

then individually set AA, BB, CC ... ZZ to ' ', but it's a lengthy process and huge code change is required.

Is there any simpler approach?

Comment: Too broad, maybe you want to have a look at designated initializers, if that is of any help.

Comment: It almost sounds like you want C++...!!!

Comment: Do you want one space or nine spaces in the strings?  In any case, you're structure is in dire need of revision as an array of 26 sub-structures.

Comment: Note that names `_X` and `__X` are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: i was looking for any pragma or any flag that can be passed to icc/gcc compiler, which might help me here, if not possible via code

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to write an initialization function:

```
void initialize(_X *x)
{
  memset(x, 0, sizeof(_X));

 x->AA[0] = ' ';
 x->BB[0] = ' ';
 // etc
 // etc
 x->ZZ[0] = ' ';
}
```

You're not going to get in much more minimal than that.

EDIT: If you're looking to fill the char arrays fully with spaces then you'll need to `memset` them, rather than set the first char to a space.

Answer (score 0):

#### Designated initializers

Assuming you want one space in the strings and zeros in the numbers, then using C99 designated initializers is going to be as compact as you can reasonably get:

```
_X x = { .AA = " ", .BB = " ", .CC = " ", …, .ZZ = " " };
```

is about the minimum you can get away with.  If you want 9 spaces per string (why?), then change the string literals to 9 spaces.  All the unmentioned elements (the `int` members) are initialized to zero.

If you need the same initialization in many places, consider creating a constant global variable that you can use when necessary:

```
const _X x_default = { .AA = " ", .BB = " ", .CC = " ", …, .ZZ = " " };
```

and then use:

```
_X other_x = x_default;
```

This can't be used to initialize global or file scope variables, but you shouldn't have many of those (`x_default` being the noticeable exception).  You can wrap this in a function, either one that takes a `_X *` argument that is initialized by assignment (`void set_x(_X *xp) { *xp = x_default; }`) or one that returns a value (`_X set_x(void) { return x_default; }`) — the choice is yours.  But the initializer should be written out as few times as possible.  Look up `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` and consider how that idea might be used, too.

If for some reason your compiler doesn't support the old C standard (C99) and only supports the archaic C standard (C90), then you have to write out the initializer fully:

```
_X x = { " ", 0, " ", 0, " ", 0, …, " ", 0 };
```

---

#### Structure design

The structure shown is problematic because of its repeated content.  It should probably be:

```
struct Y
{
    char name[10];
    int  number;
};

struct X
{
    struct Y letters[26];
};
```

Or something along those lines.  Changing that would require a lot of editing, but a lot of processing will be a lot simpler.  Funnily enough, the initialization sequence would become a little more noisy, but the fact that you don't have to write everything else out 26 times will save in the long run.

---

#### Usurping reserved identifiers

Note that the names `_X` and `__X` are both unconditionally reserved for the implementation.  Do *not* use them in your code.  Unless you really like reading the fine print, don't use names starting with underscore.  If you like the fine print, then §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers of C11 (and C99) applies:

> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
>     underscore are always reserved for any use.
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
>     with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.